# Azure EventGrid sending to internal endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Let's assume that I have a blob storage account and a VM in Azure. VM is closed to the world, has no public endpoint, however it is reachable from the inside of Azure Subscription. I would like to notify application that runs on this VM, that new file has been uploaded to my blob storage. I know that I can pass this kind of events using EventGrid. What I don't know is if it is possible to send this event to an internal endpoint, available only from VNET/Subnet.

Comment: Can you utilize an Azure Relay Hybrid Connection within a VM?

Comment: @RomanKiss That's a good questions. I'm still learning Azure, so I'll have to check it out. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Servicebus so you can keep your VM `closed to the world`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible unless you create some proxy.

You might achieve something with Azure Automation + hybrid worker combo. EventGrid can publish to Azure Automation.

Comment: Azure Automation... I have to check it out. Is something hidden from a public? Can  I use it only internally?

Comment: yes and no. i suppose eventgrid is using webhooks to start runbooks. but automation is hidden itself